# laravel save() chokes with "Integrity constraint violation" - all keys are set properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Migration:

```
Schema::create('burbs', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_location_id')->nullable()->index()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('location_id')->nullable()->index()->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Model (Burb)

```
    protected $fillable = ['parent_location_id','location_id'];
```

When i do this:

```
$burb = Burb::where(['location_id' => $location_id])->first();
    if(!$burb) $burb = new Burb;
    $burb->parent_location_id = $parent_id;
    $burb->location_id = $location_id;
    $burb->save();
```

Get This:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tb_prod`.`burbs`, CONSTRAINT
>   `burbs_location_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES
>   `locations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>
> SQL   insert into `burbs` (`parent_location_id`, `location_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (12776, 321036, 2014-10-30
>   20:38:24, 2014-10-30 20:38:24)

Both first and second Ids exist in locations table.

YES, both parent_location_id and location_id are keys to the same locations table.

I also tried: FirstOrNew([]); and FirstOrCreate([]); and I even tried

```
$burb->parent_location()->save($locationObj);
```

The last code produced "unknown method save(), while in my Burb model:

```
public function parent_location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Location','parent_location_id');
}
```

.....I am at loss, I am not new to laravel, but I just spent 3 hours debugging this. What's missing? It's driving me insane!

Comment: what happens if you do `$burb->parent_location->save($locationObj);`

Comment: Are you sure those IDs exist in the `locations` table?

Comment: maybe you're using another database, make sure that `tb_prod` database contains valid keys

Comment: Jonathan, i get "unknown method save()" error. Scopey, yeah, I ran manual "SELECT WHERE" and Razor, there is only one DB.

Answer (score 1):

is the `->index()`and`->nullable()` on your migration really necessary? they are foreign keys so,... but its up to you :D

try changing your migration to:

```
Schema::create('burbs', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('parent_location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

because last time i had the same problem but in my case i forgot to put the

> ->unsigned()

Answer (score 1):

I feel incredibly stupid. The second id (location_id) was the wrong id from the wrong table on Insert. When i ran few test cases manually (in mysql) i got lucky that those Ids existed, but it failed for most live data.

Thanks for all your help. on somewhat related note: forgetting the **->unsigned()** has given me so much grief before.